# How to install .update file on CD server for sitecore WFFM upgrade?

Tags: wffm, upgrade

> For updating sitecore WFFM the downloaded package "Web Forms for
>   Marketers 8.2 rev. 160801 (update package) NOT SC PACKAGE" consist of
>   two .update files, one for CM and one for CD server, I had updated the
>   CM instance but for CD server as we know /sitecore/admin/.. is
>   restricted , so do i will have to update those files manually or there is
>   any other way to install update on CD server ? What is the best
>   approach which will ensure that both CM and CD update are in sync ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified  upgrade package.

I suggest you to delete from CD manually files and folders from **deletedfiles** and **deletedfolders**  from the update package **Web Forms for Marketers CD 8.2 rev. 160801.update**.

And then you need to copy manually from **Web Forms for Marketers CD 8.2 rev. 160801.zip** all the files.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! But my doubt is that it is .update file , I am updating WFFM from 8.1 rev. 160523 to 8.2 rev. 160801 and the .update file contains some folder like changed files , deletedfiles , deletedfolders etc. So i can't unzip it directly to website folder on CD instance. So do i will have to overwrite and changes the files manually on CD instance or  there is any better way to do that ?